# Woocommerce installed without styling

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, styles

I built a custom wordpress theme from scretch, but when installed Woocommerce, it installed without any styling and looks like broken pages.

Is there a way to download styling for woocommerce, in order not to develop own css style for it??

Maybe if I install bootstrap it will display better?

Please, help

Comment: Have you read the documentation about using Woocommerce with custom themes? https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/

Comment: No, I'll check that out. Thanks

Comment: I applied that, but it didn't fix the issue that much... The product images, forms.. etc. is without styles

Comment: If you've followed those steps and you're still having issues you might have a problem where your own css is interfering with woocommerce css. I had a similar situation and had to basically write new css for the entire shop so that it fit with my theme.

Comment: Can I find somewhere standard default woocommerce style.css ??

Comment: 97% certain that you need to follow the instructions (I prefer the filters method) linked to by ovokuro. If you have done that, I would suggest editing your question to show what you have tried, and posting a link to your live site.